# non metacharacters to match using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to search following string with characters in a line.

```
</Connector>
```

I wrote following code. But it seems it is not finding this string. I understood that these are not metacharacters and hence should be matched automatically. Also, I checked for blanked spaces. But no avail. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
for line in wim_file:
    if re.findall("</Connector>",line):
        print('Word Found')
    else:
        print("Word Not Found!!")
```

Note: there is another string with following line which should not match.I need to match exact string with '/' character in above mentioned string.

```
        <Connector some text>
```

EDIT: please find below some more lines from text.

```
     <Connector RefLabel="70100-01-L" Tolerance="1" UniqueID="WPWDH">     
    <Property authority="Design" name="PartNumber">H1BB</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="Part">89</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="ZTH">1</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="Base">WSS Class 3</Property>
    <Property authority="Design" name="PATHID">H1BB</Property>
  </CoordinatedEntity>
</Connector>
```

Comment: how confident/sure are you that that exact line is in the file? can you include 3+ lines of the file with that line inline?

Comment: what is `wim_file`?

Comment: depperm: it is object:  wim_file = open(file_path/file_name.txt)

Comment: what is your output? I'm getting a bunch of `Word Not Found!!` then the last line is `Word Found`

Comment: looks ok now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#assuming wim_file is a filepointer
for line in wim_file.readlines():
    if re.findall(".*</Connector>.*",line):
        print('Word Found')
    else:
        print("Word Not Found!!")
```

a slight modification to the regex made me to get the required lines